Local and remote development show different tree tabs on IntelliJ IDEA
Currently I'm using IntelliJ IDEA over a remote node and some of the Tree View Tabs are missing.
Local Development.
Local
Remote Development.
Remote
How can I configure IntelliJ to recover all Tabs or is this an issue? I mostly use "Project Files" and I cannot find it.
Thank you.
